# Figure of speech when referring to a person but meaning the object (being) used by the person

Tags: figures-of-speech

In the video for Adele's Hello, at the start, she says "I just got here and I think I'm losing signal already", she does not say **her phone** is losing signal.

Is that a figure of speech and, if so, how is it called?

Answer (score 1):

It is a figure of speech, called *metonymy*. More specifically, you might regard it as *synecdoche*, though that's a bit more arguable.

Comment: Re.  synecdoche comment, it made ponder that indeed a phone is (unfortunately) almost *part* of a person in our modern world!